# Cannot get processing time out of a quicksort algorithm

Tags: c

I've been trying to get the processing time of a sorting algorithm via clock_t start, end;

But the console outputs nothing. I've been hitting this brick wall for a while and need help.

Program in question

```
// TQuicksort.c//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM 10000  //データ数
#define REPEAT 100000000  //繰り返し数

int quicksort(int a[], int first, int last) {
    int i, j, temp, x;
    
    i = first;
    j = last;
    x = (a[i] + a[j]) / 2;   //基準値は平均
    
    while (1) {
        while (a[i] < x)
            i++;
        while (a[j] > x)
            j--;
        // iがjより大きくなればwhile loopが解除される
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        //a[i]とa[j]を入れ替える
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    if (first < i - 1)
        quicksort(a, first, i - 1);
    if (j + 1 < last)
        quicksort(a, j + 1, last);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int i, n = 0;
    int a[NUM];   //配列
    
    clock_t start, end;   //clock_t型変数
    
    start = clock();   //計測開始時刻を得る
    quicksort(a, 0, NUM - 1);   //クイックソートの呼び出し
    for (i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++)  //繰り返し
        n += i * i * i * i * i;   //ダミー処理
    end = clock();   //計測終了時刻を得る
    printf("time = %.30f sec\n", ((double)end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  //処理時間の出力
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Edit: Dumbass me forgot to add an orderly array. So,
int a[NUM]; is now int a[NUM]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
New problem, changing NUM does not change the process time.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Seems like a perfect time to use a debugger - did you try that?

Comment: Probably not your main problem, but: you never storing any data in `a[]`, so you're sorting random, uninitialized data.

Comment: I think you've got infinite recursion and a stack overflow.

Comment: One simple technique is to add the line `printf("%d %d\n", first, last);` at the top of your `quicksort()` function, to see if the recursion is proceeding as you expect.

Comment: Oh, right. I completely forgot that a Quicksort algorithm needs an orderly array to function. Ok, I've fixed that but now there's a new issue. Even with adjusting the NUM value, the processing time is not changing. What now?

Comment: What is this code for? `for(i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++) n += i * i * i * i * i;`

Comment: What kind of times are you getting?

Comment: I was told to input a dummy process so that the program would repeat. I am getting a time of 0.178 seconds from NUM 1000 to NUM 10000. Is it normal for a Quicksort algorithm to have a consistent processing time no matter the size of numbers in the algorithm or am I loosing it?

Comment: I believe there's something wrong with your recursion.  It's not true that "Quicksort needs an orderly array to function".  I added the initialization `for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++) a[i] = rand();`,  and there were 24,029,360 recursive calls before I hit control-C to kill it.

Comment: It is difficult to accurately time something that takes less than a second.  So the usual technique is to run the thing for N = hundreds or thousands of times, and divide the overall time by N.  That is, if "x" is the time your thing (in this case, your quicksort call) takes to run, you take TIME(N*x) ÷ N.  But here you're doing TIME(x + y), where "y" is the time taken to do some completely separate, unrelated task, and that gives you a meaningless result.

Comment: It's likely that both NUM=1000 and NUM=10000 were so fast that the time was nearly 0, and the unrelated REPEAT loop took all the time.

Comment: But before you try to figure out how fast your quicksort function actually is, you need to fix its logic so it actually works!

Comment: the code sample you provided does not work, your  `quicksort` function cause a segfault, it crash before going to call `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `x = (a[i] + a[j]) / 2;` may overflow, which has undefined behavior, and produce a value that is not even between `a[i]` and `a[j]`, potentially causing an infinite recursion.
- `int a[NUM];` is not initialized
- the `REPEAT` loop produces a value of `n` with computations that will likely overflow and that is not used, the code is probably removed by the optimizing compiler.

You must be careful to compute the mid point without overflow. If type `long long` is larger than `int`, you can use:

```
    int x = ((long long)a[i] + a[j]) / 2;
```

Here is a modified version, benchmarking various distributions:

```
//TQuicksort.c//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM 100000

void quicksort(int a[], int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int i = first;
        int j = last;
        int x = ((long long)a[i] + a[j]) / 2;
        int temp;

        for (;;) {
            while (a[i] < x)
                i++;
            while (a[j] > x)
                j--;
            if (i >= j)
                break;
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        quicksort(a, first, i - 1);
        quicksort(a, j + 1, last);
    }
}

int min(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

clock_t test(const char *s, int *a, int len) {
    clock_t c = clock();
    quicksort(a, 0, len - 1);
    c = clock() - c;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i - 1]) {
            printf("%s: failed\n", s);
            break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int max = argc > 1 ? strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 0) : NUM;
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * max);
    const char *name[] = { "rand", "bytes", "bits", "zero", "incr", "decr", "hat" };
    clock_t c[10][7];
    int i, j, k, len;

    for (k = 0, len = max; len >= 10; len /= 10, k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = rand();       // random ints
        c[k][0] = test(name[0], a, len);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = rand() & 255; // random bytes
        c[k][1] = test(name[1], a, len);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = rand() & 1;   // random bits
        c[k][2] = test(name[2], a, len);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = 0;            // all zeroes
        c[k][3] = test(name[3], a, len);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = i;            // monotonic increase
        c[k][4] = test(name[4], a, len);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = -i;           // monotonic decrease
        c[k][5] = test(name[5], a, len);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = min(i, len - i - 1); // hat shape
        c[k][6] = test(name[6], a, len);
    }
    printf("%10s", "length");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        printf("%9s ", name[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0, len = max; j < k; j++, len /= 10) {
        printf("%10d", len);
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            printf(" %9.3f", c[j][i] * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output for `100000000`:

```
    length     rand     bytes      bits      zero      incr      decr       hat
 100000000 11073.979  5026.436  2948.862  2456.532  1431.838  1487.996  6790.571
  10000000   971.453   467.954   260.339   239.740   128.600   135.692   573.682
   1000000    86.910    46.189    36.059    31.516    14.522    13.370    57.162
    100000     7.578     4.350     2.529     2.301     1.002     1.510     4.835
     10000     0.748     0.524     0.190     0.145     0.076     0.106     0.502
      1000     0.066     0.055     0.027     0.018     0.013     0.012     0.045
       100     0.007     0.007     0.004     0.002     0.003     0.002     0.004
        10     0.001     0.001     0.000     0.000     0.001     0.002     0.001
```

As you can see, the timings are quite different depending on the distribution of numbers. A random distribution causing the most mispredictions in the scanning loops, hence is slower than one with substantial numbers of duplicates, and sorted arrays are even faster because the comparisons are well predicted and fewer swaps occur.

The time complexity should be **O(N log(N))** on average and the observed timings for large arrays are consistent with this.